# Retentions policy understand fro Graphite DB

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon

I have the below retentions policy mention in `storage-schemas.conf` file

```
[metrics]
pattern = ^metrics.api.*
retentions = 10s:5m,1m:1d,1h:30d,1d:1y,30d:10y
```

Below is my understanding
 this policy runs for the matched pattern starting with metrics.api*

**1st: 10s:5m** ->  1 or more times record inserted at 10s then its will take the latest record and maintain 1 datapoint , till 5min its maintains the history say suppose in 5m 5 datapoints added for the metrics key.

**2nd:1m:1d** -> this second run after the 5min overs for the same metrics key ,1  or more times record inserted at 1m then its will take the latest record and maintain 1 datapoint,till 1d its maintains the history say suppose in 1d 15 datapoints added for the metrics key.

so my question is what happens for these 2 retention is it will do the average 1st 5+15/2= 10 ? and get one average data point  out of this 1st and 2nd rentions

--- its goes till 10years of data to be stored

can you please explain on the above retention polciy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aggregationMethod will be applied on this retention policy when switching boundaries.
First retention - 10s:5m means Graphite will store 30 datapoints (every 10 seconds for last 5 minutes) in archive 0.

Please note, that it will always store these datapoints, even if no data arrived. In that case Graphite will put NULLs there.

Then next retention - 1m:1d means that every minute whisper will take 6 of these 10s datapoints from archive 0, apply average() function and store them in archive 1.
But please note that Whisper will do so only if at least 3 (number of datapoints - 6 multiplied by xFilesFactor = 0.5) or more points in archive 0 have values (i.e. not NULLs). Otherwise Whisper decides that it has not enough data to propagate and put also NULL instead.

Etc - third retention 1h:30d means that 60 of datapoints from archive 1 will be aggregated using average function and propagated to archive 2, but only if at least 30 of them have value, etc.